# Is there a way to disable a button for 24 hours?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, cookies, onclick

Alright, so I was looking for how to do this: When a button is clicked, it is then disabled and turned into a countdown timer for 24 hours. I could not find any way to do this. For an example, see this: http://www.donaldscott.com/Minecraft/interface.php?noCache=10

It needs to allow you to click a button, disable it for 24 hours using the `onclick` function, and then display a countdown for that button. When you refresh the page, it will continue the countdown.   Can you do this with cookies? jQuery? Help me please :)

Comment: Cookies can be easily bypassed by clearing the browser's cookies. If you don't have a login and server-side validation, it won't be a safe thing to do.

Comment: I do have a database, but already have a separate mysql verification system for my script. I just want this for aesthetics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the countdown with cookies:

http://www.wezelkrozum.nl/temp/countdown.php

Please note that this is no safe method. Save the time the user has to wait on the serverside so the user can't change the value.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to do this:

1. By storing something on the user's machine.
2. By storing something on your server specific to that user.

Cookies are an example of option 1. The upside to this approach is that it's much easier than the alternative. The downside is that it's not very hard for users to clear cookies, or any other form of local storage. If your webapp depends on the user not being able to click that button again for 24 hours, cookies are not a safe approach.

Option 2 is much more complicated. You'll need to store something you know about the user in a database on your server, and use that information to decide whether or not to enable the button and what time to show on the counter.

Deciding what to store is tricky. The only really safe thing to store is a login token (do users log in to use your app?). This way you have a unique token for each user, it doesn't matter if the user logs in from another computer, etc. The other ways to do it are with session cookies (same problems as option 1) or by storing the IP address (better, but still not reliable, especially for users on mobile devices or laptops.)

Unless you already have a database set up, and use some server-side code to generate views, and have a login mechanism, you probably want to consider how important this feature is. It will be a ton of work to add all of that just for this one button.